# Conjugation tables for French

Tags: c#, lookup

I'm in the process of structuring a model for conjugation tables for French. There are noun inflections, adverb inflections, and 19 verb conjugations. I'm trying to model the data so that every piece of data is accessible in the same manner as one would traverse the following XML tree (taken from my XML dictionary file):

```xml
<Word word="être" aspirate="false">
    <GrammaticalForms>
      <GrammaticalForm form="nm" definition="A being (e.g. animal, insect)."></GrammaticalForm>
      <GrammaticalForm form="vi" definition="The be (a state of existence)."></GrammaticalForm>
    </GrammaticalForms>
    <ConjugationTables>
      <NounTable ms="être" fs="" mpl="êtres" fpl="" gender="m"></NounTable>
      <AdjectiveTable ms="" fs="" mpl="" fpl="" na=""></AdjectiveTable>
      <VerbTable group="e" auxillary="a" prepositions="à, de, des, en" transitive="false" pronominal="false">
        <Indicative>
          <Present fps="suis" sps="es" tps="est" fpp="sommes" spp="êtes" tpp="sont"></Present>
          <SimplePast fps="fus" sps="fus" tps="fut" fpp="fûmes" spp="fûtes" tpp="furent"></SimplePast>
          <PresentPerfect fps="ai été" sps="as été" tps="a été" fpp="avons été" spp="avez été" tpp="ont été"></PresentPerfect>
          <PastPerfect fps="eus été" sps="eus été" tps="eut été" fpp="eûmes été" spp="eûtes été" tpp="eurent été"></PastPerfect>
          <Imperfect fps="étais" sps="étais" tps="était" fpp="étions" spp="étiez" tpp="étaient"></Imperfect>
          <Pluperfect fps="avais été" sps="avais été" tps="avait été" fpp="avions été" spp="aviez été" tpp="avaient été"></Pluperfect>
          <Future fps="serai" sps="seras" tps="sera" fpp="serons" spp="serez" tpp="seront"></Future>
          <PastFuture fps="aurai été" sps="auras été" tps="aura été" fpp="aurons été" spp="aurez été" tpp="auront été"></PastFuture>
        </Indicative>
        <Subjunctive>
          <Present fps="sois" sps="sois" tps="soit" fpp="soyons" spp="soyez" tpp="soient"></Present>
          <Past fps="aie été" sps="aies été" tps="ait été" fpp="ayons été" spp="ayez été" tpp="aient été"></Past>
          <Imperfect fps="fusse" sps="fusses" tps="fût" fpp="fussions" spp="fussiez" tpp="fussent"></Imperfect>
          <Pluperfect fps="eusse été" sps="eusses été" tps="eût été" fpp="eussions été" spp="eussiez été" tpp="eussent été"></Pluperfect>
        </Subjunctive>
        <Conditional>
          <Present fps="serais" sps="serais" tps="serait" fpp="serions" spp="seriez" tpp="seraient"></Present>
          <FirstPast fps="aurais été" sps="aurais été" tps="aurait été" fpp="aurions été" spp="auriez été" tpp="auraient été"></FirstPast>
          <SecondPast fps="eusse été" sps="eusses été" tps="eût été" fpp="eussions été" spp="eussiez été" tpp="eussent été"></SecondPast>
        </Conditional>
        <Imperative>
          <Present sps="sois" fpp="soyons" spp="soyez"></Present>
          <Past sps="aie été" fpp="ayons été" spp="ayez été"></Past>
        </Imperative>
        <Infinitive present="être" past="avoir été"></Infinitive>
        <Participle present="étant" past="été"></Participle>
      </VerbTable>
    </ConjugationTables>
  </Word>
```

Here is the way that I've found to model the data. This is *simply a storage mechanism*. Basically it's necessary to have the entire dictionary in memory (maybe excluding standard verb conjugations but that just makes things more complicated - I can optimize on that later). This will allow instant lookup of a word in the application. The `Word`s will be stored in a `SortedDictionary` as a data member of another class. There will also be a separate implementation of a spell checker.

*Grammar-specific data should not be a part of this schema*. Simply put, special exceptions such as the word *bel* (inflection of *beau* coming before a word that starts with a vowel) will be handled separately in the *grammar interface of the application*. This design is meant to store common attributes among all words in a dictionary, such as noun/adjective inflections, verb conjugations, and other small pieces of data like definition(s), grammatical forms the word has, etc.

Here's what I have, and will improve upon based on other answers noted here (at least to the best of my ability):

```cs
class Word
{
    // the infinitive Word in the Dictionary
    public string word { get; set; }
    // Whether or not the Word is aspirate - adjective forms and phonetics change.
    public bool aspirate { get; set; }
    /*
     * The list of grammatical forms that this Word can have. For example, 'être':
     * 'être' --> vi (verb intransitive) "to be".
     * '(un) être' --> nm (noun masculin) "(a) being".
     */
    public List<GrammaticalForm> forms { get; set; }

    public struct GrammaticalForm
    {
        // The grammatical identifier of the form (e.g., 'vi' or 'nm'). --> ENUM LATER
        public string form { get; set; }
        // The definition (meaning) of the Word in a particular form.
        public string definition { get; set; }
    }

    // The table of noun INFLECTIONS, if the Word has a grammatical form of a noun.
    public NounTable nounTable { get; set; }
    // The table of adjective INFLECTIONS, if the Word has a grammatical form of an adjective.
    public AdjectiveTable adjectiveTable { get; set; }
    // The table of verb conjugations, if the Word has a grammatical form of a verb.
    public VerbTable verbTable { get; set; }
}

abstract class ConjugationTable
{
    // If there are any properties that would eventually be shared among all conjugation
    // types, they would go here.
}

class NounTable : ConjugationTable
{
    /*
     * The gender of the noun:
     * 'ms' (masculin singular)
     * 'fs' (feminin singular)
     * 'mpl' (masculin plural)
     * 'fpl' (feminin plural)
     */
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string ms { get; set; }
    public string fs { get; set; }
    public string mpl { get; set; }
    public string fpl { get; set; }
}

class AdjectiveTable : ConjugationTable
{
    /*
     * The gender of the adjective:
     * 'ms' (masculin singular)
     * 'fs' (feminin singular)
     * 'mpl' (masculin plural)
     * 'fpl' (feminin plural)
     * 'na' (non-aspirate)
     */
    public string ms { get; set; }
    public string fs { get; set; }
    public string mpl { get; set; }
    public string fpl { get; set; }
    public string na { get; set; }
    /*
     * The location of the adjective around the noun:
     * 'b' (before)
     * 'a' (after)
     * 'n' (neutral) --> the adjective can come before OR after the noun.
     */
    public char location { get; set; }
}

class VerbTable : ConjugationTable
{
    /* 
     * The group the verb belongs to:
     * 'f' (first) --> er.
     * 's' (second) --> ir.
     * 't' (third) --> ir, oir, re.
     * 'e' (exception) --> être, avoir, etc.
     */
    public char group { get; set; }
    /*
     * The auxillary verb the verb takes:
     * 'e' (être).
     * 'a' (avoir).
     */
    public char auxillary { get; set; }
    // A list of grammatically-valid prepositions the verb can take.
    public string[] prepositions { get; set; }
    // Whether or not the verb is transitive.
    public bool transitive { get; set; }
    /*
     * Whether or not the verb has a pronominal form. If true, a function will later
     * conjugate the pronominal infinitive of the verb for lookup in the Dictionary.
     * This saves space over allocating a string of the conjugated pronominal infinitive.
     */
    public bool pronominal { get; set; }

    /*
     * The subject of the verb determined by the markers:
     * 'fps' (first person singular)
     * 'sps' (second person singular)
     * 'tps' (third person singular)
     * 'fpp' (first person plural)
     * 'spp' (second person plural)
     * 'tpp' (third person plural)
     * 'present' (present tense)
     * 'past' (past tense)
     * and their accompanying conjugations.
     */

    // All of the different conjugation types are instantiated
    // when a VerbTable is instantiated.

    public IndicativePresent indicativePresent = new IndicativePresent();
    public IndicativeSimplePast indicativeSimplePast = new IndicativeSimplePast();
    public IndicativePresentPerfect indicativePresentPerfect = new IndicativePresentPerfect();
    public IndicativePastPerfect indicativePastPerfect = new IndicativePastPerfect();
    public IndicativeImperfect indicativeImperfect = new IndicativeImperfect();
    public IndicativePluperfect indicativePluperfect = new IndicativePluperfect();
    public IndicativeFuture indicativeFuture = new IndicativeFuture();
    public IndicativePastFuture indicativePastFuture = new IndicativePastFuture();
    public SubjunctivePresent subjunctivePresent = new SubjunctivePresent();
    public SubjunctivePast subjunctivePast = new SubjunctivePast();
    public SubjunctiveImperfect subjunctiveImperfect = new SubjunctiveImperfect();
    public SubjunctivePluperfect subjunctivePluperfect = new SubjunctivePluperfect();
    public ConditionalPresent conditionalPresent = new ConditionalPresent();
    public ConditionalFirstPast conditionalFirstPast = new ConditionalFirstPast();
    public ConditionalSecondPast conditionalSecondPast = new ConditionalSecondPast();
    public ImperativePresent imperativePresent = new ImperativePresent();
    public ImperativePast imperativePast = new ImperativePast();
    public Infinitive infinitive = new Infinitive();
    public Participle participle = new Participle();
}

abstract class Indicative
{
    // Any common elements that indicative tenses share.
    public abstract string fps { get; set; }
    public abstract string sps { get; set; }
    public abstract string tps { get; set; }
    public abstract string fpp { get; set; }
    public abstract string spp { get; set; }
    public abstract string tpp { get; set; }
}

abstract class Subjunctive
{
    // Any common elements that subjunctive tenses share.
    public abstract string fps { get; set; }
    public abstract string sps { get; set; }
    public abstract string tps { get; set; }
    public abstract string fpp { get; set; }
    public abstract string spp { get; set; }
    public abstract string tpp { get; set; }
}

abstract class Conditional
{
    // Any common elements that conditional tenses share.
    public abstract string fps { get; set; }
    public abstract string sps { get; set; }
    public abstract string tps { get; set; }
    public abstract string fpp { get; set; }
    public abstract string spp { get; set; }
    public abstract string tpp { get; set; }
}

abstract class Imperative
{
    // Any common elements that imperative tenses share.
    public abstract string sps { get; set; }
    public abstract string fpp { get; set; }
    public abstract string spp { get; set; }
}

class IndicativePresent : Indicative
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class IndicativeSimplePast : Indicative
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class IndicativePresentPerfect : Indicative
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class IndicativePastPerfect : Indicative
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class IndicativeImperfect : Indicative
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class IndicativePluperfect : Indicative
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class IndicativeFuture : Indicative
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class IndicativePastFuture : Indicative
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class SubjunctivePresent : Subjunctive
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class SubjunctivePast : Subjunctive
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class SubjunctiveImperfect : Subjunctive
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class SubjunctivePluperfect : Subjunctive
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class ConditionalPresent : Conditional
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class ConditionalFirstPast : Conditional
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class ConditionalSecondPast : Conditional
{
    public override string fps { get; set; }
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string tps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
    public override string tpp { get; set; }
}

class ImperativePresent : Imperative
{
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
}

class ImperativePast : Imperative
{
    public override string sps { get; set; }
    public override string fpp { get; set; }
    public override string spp { get; set; }
}

class Infinitive
{
    public string present { get; set; }
    public string past { get; set; }
}

class Participle
{
    public string present { get; set; }
    public string past { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Theoretical upvote (ran out of votes!) - I somewhat hope this one doesn't get answered before I get home... for now I'll just say you need `enum`s and more descriptive naming. Identifiers shouldn't need a comment to explain what they mean ;)

Comment: Also, design for simplicity, maintainability and readability. Performance optimizations are a distant last concern.

Comment: I'm just trying to think ahead a bit because there will be at least 25,000 words in the standard French dictionary that will have one or more of these tables filled out (3,000+ verbs), so I'm trying to make memory management one of my concerns early on :) as for the *descriptive naming*... I named things like `fps` in lieu of `firstPersonSingular` because I imagined that declarations like: `Word.VerbTable.IndicativePresent.firstPersonSingluar` was a bit long... there are only 13 identifiers like `fps`, and they seem to me to be logical shorthand, and can be explained in a total of 3 comments.

Comment: In common usage, [_conjugation_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjugation) applies only to verbs. [_Inflection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) is the general term for all grammatically required word modifications.

Comment: Good point about the conjugation vs inflection - Perhaps I should modify my structure to reflect that; in fact, that makes things a lot less confusing, I can't believe I didn't think about that. When I started learning French, they never use the word 'inflection' even once, just the *forms* (masculin singular, feminin plural, etc.). And since I never took any classes about English grammar, I never even though about that :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see what we've got here: a `NounTable`, inherited from a `ConjugationTable`. As I mentioned in the comments, this huge comment is unnecessary.

You say you're worried about memory? `string` is a reference type, with the overhead it incurs. Consider this (I renamed the identifiers just to <s>mess you up</s> see what it would look like):

```
public enum Genre
{
    Indéterminé,
    Masculin,
    Feminin
}

public enum Nombre
{
    Singulier,
    Pluriel
}

public struct Nom
{
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public Nombre Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Notice I haven't derived the `NounTable` class from a base type. *You Ain't Gonna Need It*. Besides, you don't derive a bunch of classes because you want to *share functionality* - remember, a base class puts your type in a **is-a** inheritance scheme, and if all you want is shared functionality you should favor *composition over inheritance*. Anyway I made it a `struct` that stores what can be seen as two `int` values. It's just fortunate that this happens to mootinate the long comment ;)

---

What's your spec? Are you implementing the French grammar? I was going to make a long rewrite of the thing - given how simple it is to conjugate 90% of French verbs (1st group), I was going to suggest *coding the grammar* for it - this could spare you from storing 90% of your verbs dictionary.

And then I deleted it all, it wasn't going to be a helpful answer.

Your code is making [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) mistakes that ought to be addressed first.

**If you're copying code, you're doing it wrong.**

When you create a base class, its inheritors *actually inherit* the base members, so any class derived from `Indicative` does not need to re-implement the base members... but because you have declared them `abstract`, now you *have* to. They could have been `virtual` and that would have left you with classes that look like this:

```
class IndicativePresent : Indicative
{
}
```

Not very useful is it? I think all these classes are trying to do one thing: store a string value for the result of the conjugation of a *verb* at a specified *tense*, for each *person*. If that's the case, you could have a `IReadOnlyDictionary<IPronoun, string>` as a sole member.

I'll end this with a bit of abstract food for thought - if what you're trying to do is really *modelize* French and *implement its grammar*, you're probably better off defining every concept as an *abstraction*:

```
public enum Person
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}

public enum Gender
{
    Undetermined,
    Masculine,
    Feminine
}

public enum Number
{
    Singular,
    Plural
}

public interface IPronoun
{
    Person Person { get; }
    Gender Gender { get; }
    Number Number { get; }
    string Text { get; }
}

public enum VerbGroup
{
    First,
    Second,
    Third
}

public enum VerbAuxiliary
{
    ToHave,
    ToBe
}

public enum VerbTense
{
    Present,
    Past,
    Future
}

public enum VerbMood
{
    Infinitive,
    Indicative,
    Imperative,
    Conditional,
    Subjonctive,
    Participle,
    Gerundive
}

public enum VerbTransitivity
{
    Intransitive,
    Direct,
    Indirect,
    //...
}

public interface IVerb
{
    string InfinitivePresent { get; }
    VerbGroup { get; }
    bool IsPronomial { get; }

    // having these below members here implies the transitive and intransitive forms of
    //  { descendre, monter, passer, redescendre, remonter, rentrer, 
    //   repasser, ressortir, ressusciter, retourner, sortir, tomber}
    // must be implemented as distinct instances.
    VerbAuxiliary { get; }
    VerbTransitivity Transitivity { get; }
}

public interface IConjugable
{
    // an overload taking an IVerb with VerbAuxiliary and VerbTransitivity parameters
    // would allow us to remove these two members from the IVerb implementations,
    // allowing verbs like "passer" and "sortir" (^^^) to only be implemented once.
    string Conjugate(IPronoun subject);
}
```

---

If all you're trying to do is to read data from a source, your [data-structures](/questions/tagged/data-structures) should simply reflect it. It feels to me that the inheritance hierarchy obscures the intent of the code, which makes it hard to review without a bit more context.

Comment: This, at first glance looks like a very useful answer, so thanks first off! But right now I don't have time to read it fully - I will definitely take a look when I get back from class today! I likely made a lot of design mistakes because this is actually my first-ever project in C#, and I've never really done Object-Oriented programming so concepts like `abstract`, `composition`, `inheritence` and the like are all unfamiliar to me.

Comment: How about `: byte` in the enums?

Comment: Also, every tense has either one, three or six pronouns, I wouldn't use a dictionary (dictionaries have a significant overhead)

Comment: I added a *lot* more context to my answer, as well as an example of XML data that I will be storing in the application, and what the intent of this organizational schema is. I hope this helps! I'm also thinking that, although `Enum`s are great, I need to store *actual `string` data* in most of these cases, so `Enum`s would only be effective for modeling grammar patterns (which I eventually intend to do!), and not *store data*. Does this significantly change the domain of the problem?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice absolutely! Now we're talking more about *xml deserialization* than anything else - I think. (only glanced at your update)

Comment: That's exactly what it is haha, *not grammar yet*! I would like to retain, as much as possible, the structure of the XML file. I think I did a fairly good job then - as I remember you saying, `abstract` is a way to say **is-a** in a relational sense. That being said, I guess I'm still not sure that I did the abstraction correctly, because I feel that repeating the `public override` several times throughout the classes is a bit tedious and sloppy - however, isn't it *necessary* when you implement `abstract` class members? **That** structure will stay **static** so maybe it's a non-issue...

Comment: There are tools for this! You can create a schema from your xml, and from the schema you can *generate* classes that perfectly map to your xml structure - you don't even have to actually write any of these classes yourself :) research what xsd.exe can do for you :)

Comment: As for `abstract` members, you are right - they **must** be overridden. But who said an `abstract` class *had* to have `abstract` members? You make a class `abstract` because you don't want that class directly instantiated; this buys you the *possibility* to have `abstract` members - they don't *have* to be. And by *not being abstract*, the members are simply inherited. If you want them overridable, you can make them `virtual`, but I don't think I see an immediate need for that.

Comment: @lol.upvote It's interesting... there is a guy collaborating with me on this, building the UI and stuff - I guess he didn't know about that feature but it's funny because he just mentioned in an email to me that he designed a .xaml file, and Visual Studio generated a bunch of other code for him. I guess I just don't know all the power that's at my fingertips ;) in any case, I'll take a look at the auto-generation stuff. Your answer, as well as 200_success' will be very useful for modeling the *grammar*, so thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll comment mainly on the *querying interface*, as I don't have good ideas for how to *store* all those word forms at this point.

You have a small combinatorial explosion problem that you should probably acknowledge.  In French, inflection of nouns and adjectives depends mainly on gender and number, so you should expose an `Inflect()` method that accepts two independent arguments, rather than four no-argument getters.  The interface with independent arguments becomes more obviously superior when it comes to verbs, which also depend on the person, tense, and mood.

As is common in human languages, there are some exceptional cases that you may wish to consider.  For example, the adjective [*beau*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/beau) comes in forms

- *beau* (masculine singular)
- *belle* (feminine singular)
- *beaux* (masculine plural)
- *belles* (feminine plural)

However, the masculine singular becomes *bel* when it precedes a word that begins with a vowel or silent h.  Furthermore, the following word doesn't necessarily have to be the noun being modified (e.g. *un bel et vaste salon*).  There are probably other examples and arguments for keeping the interfaces flexible enough to handle such language warts.

Verb groups should probably be first, second, third, irregular (e.g. *être*), and defective (e.g. *falloir*).

Comment: I do like your idea of having an interface for inflections - however, this design is simply to store all data for a word. Grammatically-related topics are not part of this code at all, aside from the *common attributes* that these types of words share. For example, your remark about the word *bel* (from *beau) in `ms` form, when in front of (any) word that starts with a vowel, is purely grammatical, and should thus be omitted from this structure, especially because it is a rare exception. Non-aspirate forms are much more common, so I decided to store them in the table.

Comment: In fact, the verb groups follow a similar pattern - there are *first*, *second*, *third*, and *irregular* verb groups. I'll eventually write an algorithm to conjugate the regular verbs to auto-fill data in my XML dictionary file for me, but *falloir* is a very rare exception, such that the only real difference between it and *être* is that *falloir* will have 'empty data' in many of its verb tables. This is an exception that, in the *storage* schema, is really irrelevant, because this is going to be a "click here to get all data about a word" schema. Grammar is coming later :)

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments in a row - but last thing: I updated my question to reflect the *goal* of this organizational structure, as well as an example of the data that I will be storing. I think that will help clarify what I'm trying to do here - your suggestions are more *grammar*-related, which I will definitely thoroughly consider when I actually start writing that interface! For now though, it's just getting all the data into the application, so that it is accessible in a manner that makes sense (following the XML data, which has a hierarchical pattern that I want to follow).